# select customer buy items in 2 dictionaries in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to filter the customer who bought both items in the `list_1` and `list_2` OR customer who bought both `S/M` and `L/XL` from one `list_1`  OR customer who bought both `S/M` and `L/XL` from one `list_2`

```
list_1 = [A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, D1, D2]

list_2 = [E1, E2, F1, F2, G1, G2, H1, H2]
```

| customer_id | item | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | S/M |
| 2 | G1 | S/M |
| 3 | D1 | S/M |
| 1 | E2 | L/XL |
| 2 | H2 | L/XL |
| 9 | D1 | S/M |
| 1 | G1 | S/M |
| 9 | H2 | L/XL |
| 2 | H2 | L/XL |

I want to extract the following table

| customer_id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 2 | G1 |
| 1 | E2 |
| 9 | D1 |
| 1 | G1 |
| 9 | H2 |
| 2 | H2 |

I can get the customer who bought both items in the `list_1` and `list_2`

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('customer_id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = (df.select('*',
                F.col('item').isin(list_1).alias('list_1'),
                F.col('item').isin(list_2).alias('list_2'))
      .select('customer_id', 'item',
              # If there is any True for a customer, take the True value
              F.max('list_1').over(w).alias('list_1'),
              F.max('list_2').over(w).alias('list_2'))
      .filter(F.col('list_1') & F.col('list_2'))
      .select('customer_id', 'item'))
```

But got stuck about filtering customer who bought both `S/M` and `L/XL` from one `list_1`  OR customer who bought both `S/M` and `L/XL` from one `list_2`. I think about  creating a dictionary

```
dict_1 = {"A1" : "S/M", "A2" : "L/XL", "B1" : "S/M", "B2" : "L/XL", "C1" : "S/M", "C2" : "L/XL","D1" : "S/M", "D2" : "L/XL"}

dict_2 = {"E1" : "S/M", "E2" : "L/XL", "F1" : "S/M", "F2" : "L/XL", "G1" : "S/M", "G2" : "L/XL", "H1" : "S/M", "H2" : "L/XL"}
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Let me know what you think about this solution?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

output_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('list_1', f.array(*[f.lit(element) for element in list_1]))
    .withColumn('list_2', f.array(*[f.lit(element) for element in list_2]))
    .withColumn('which_list', f.when(f.array_contains(f.col('list_1'), f.col('item')), f.lit('list_1')).otherwise(f.lit('list_2')))
    .withColumn('size_list', f.concat_ws('|', f.col('size'), f.col('which_list')))
    .groupBy('customer_id')
    .agg(
        f.collect_list(f.col('which_list')).alias('which_lists')
        f.collect_list(f.col('size_list')).alias('size_lists')
    )
    .where(
        (
            f.array_contains(f.col('which_lists'), 'lists_1') &
            f.array_contains(f.col('which_lists'), 'lists_2')
        ) |
        (
            f.array_contains(f.col('size_lists'), 'S/M|list_1') &
            f.array_contains(f.col('size_lists'), 'L/XL|list_1')
        ) |
        (
            f.array_contains(f.col('size_lists'), 'S/M|list_2') &
            f.array_contains(f.col('size_lists'), 'L/XL|list_2')
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Will this handle the case if a `S/M` is picked from one list and the `L/XL` is picked from other list?

Comment: You're right; it didn't. I've fixed the solution.

Comment: does it cover the case `which_lists` or `size_lists` is empty list because I got the error `input to function arrays_overlap should have been 
two arrays with same element type, but it's [array, array];`

Comment: @DucVu I have updated the solution to cover the scenario that Islam Elbanna brought up. This solution is not using `arrays_overlap` anymore.

Comment: How can I get all new table including customer _id, item and size with the filtered customer_id ?

Comment: @DucVu off the top of my head you can join the `output_df` with the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```py
s_m = "S/M"
l_xl = "L/XL"
w = Window.partitionBy('customer_id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = (df.select('*',
            F.col('item').isin(list_1).alias('list_1'),
            F.col('item').isin(list_2).alias('list_2'),
            when(F.col('item').isin(list_1) && F.col("size") === s_m, 1).otherwise(0).alias('list_1_s_m'),
            when(F.col('item').isin(list_1) && F.col("size") === l_xl, 1).otherwise(0).alias('list_1_l_xl'),
            when(F.col('item').isin(list_2) && F.col("size") === s_m, 1).otherwise(0).alias('list_2_s_m'),
            when(F.col('item').isin(list_2) && F.col("size") === l_xl, 1).otherwise(0).alias('list_2_l_xl'))
  .select('customer_id', 'item',
          # If there is any True for a customer, take the True value
          F.max('list_1').over(w).alias('list_1'),
          F.max('list_2').over(w).alias('list_2'),
          F.sum('list_1_s_m').over(w).alias('list_1_s_m'),
          F.sum('list_2_s_m').over(w).alias('list_2_s_m'),
          F.sum('list_1_l_xl').over(w).alias('list_1_l_xl'),
          F.sum('list_2_l_xl').over(w).alias('list_2_l_xl'))
  .filter((F.col('list_1') & F.col('list_2')) 
          | (F.col('list_1_s_m') > 0 & F.col('list_1_l_xl') > 0)
          | (F.col('list_2_s_m') > 0 & F.col('list_2_l_xl') > 0))
  .select('customer_id', 'item'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach by counting the number of distinct sizes per each list.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('customer_id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
wsize = Window.partitionBy('customer_id', 'list_num').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = (df.select('*',
                # Bucket to which list an item belongs to
                F.when(F.col('item').isin(list_1).alias('list_1'), F.lit('list_1'))
                 .when(F.col('item').isin(list_2).alias('list_2'), F.lit('list_2')).alias('list_num'))
      # count distinct size in each list
      .withColumn('size_cnt', F.size(F.collect_set('size').over(wsize)))
      # Max count per customer and then filter a customer buys 2 sizes (assuming there are only S/M, L/XL, otherwise tweak this) from either list.
      .withColumn('max_size_cnt', F.max(F.col('size_cnt')).over(w))
      .filter(F.col('max_size_cnt') == 2)
      .select('customer_id', 'item'))
```